# How to draw a circle around a circle in a css ::after selector?

Tags: css

I have a simple div with a radius-border: 50%. It looks like a circle. When hovering this circle I need to display a bigger circle around it, with a different color. Here is a picture to show the kind of rendering I'm looking for:

[image]

Because I am using a slider library, I probably need to use the ::after selector inside an hover. How would you do it?

My code :

```css
#inner-circle{
     position: absolute;
      margin-left: -8px;
      margin-top: -6.5px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: solid 2px green;
      background-color: green;
}

#inner-circle::after{
  content: "";
    border-radius: 50%;
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 24px orange;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code?

Comment: What library do you use ?

Comment: @julien rc-slider .

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 my css doesn't work so it's useless.

Comment: The question is going to get down voted because it appears the OP did not give effort in solving the problem (i.e., no current code was shown). Therefore, this is looking more like a freelance job and less than a Stack Overflow question. Please read here, friend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Ok, the code is now in the question. However, I think it's useless because this css doesn't work and don't provide any valuable insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box shadow to get the same effect, just use hover to show the box shadow on hover. rgba(135,206,235, 0.3) => here 0.3 is opacity of the outer circle.

```css
.circle-with-hover{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor:pointer; 
  transition:.3s;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.circle-with-hover:hover{
 box-shadow:  0 0 0 13px rgba(135,206,235, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="circle-with-hover">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried box-shadow, but it was never correctly centered and its borders were vanishing instead of staying sharp. You solution is perfect!